# Angular App - Intranet Site - Save assets outside of temp cache folder

Tags: html, angularjs

I believe I already know the answer to this question, but need to ask to the general public, just to make sure I'm not missing anything.

We have an Angular app that we built for our client, that runs on their intranet site in all of their stores.

The issue we're facing, is that every time the browser is closed, it automatically clears the cache. Thus, when they re-open the site, due to the slow connection they have to all of their sites, it take awhile for the pages to load (imagery heavy).

Something we're looking to doing, is on load, having a loader indicator that is displayed while all the assets (images) are lazy loaded in.

But outside of this, I was just curious, is their a way to save the sites assets and save them outside of IE's temporary folder, so clear the caching automatically on close won't actually remove the assets that are cache.

Thanks,

Comment: Is there a real reason why the cache is cleaned? This is exactly what it is for. This would be possible with [Service Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#Install_and_activate_populating_your_cache). They are not supported in IE. [AppCache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache) is, on the other hand.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but in the event you can't get around having the cache cleared, make sure you are minifying your js.  A good practice regardless.

Comment: @estus Found out, it's a policy on their office PC's, that every time the browser is closed, it automatically clears the cache.

Comment: @Whnunlife If AppCache doesn't work for you in IE then you're out of options. At this point I would consider migrating to Electron/NW.js desktop app from 'industry standard' IE.